# How can i edit all posts slug in bulk keeping WP native redirect?

Tags: permalinks, slug, bulk

When i edit a single post slug the old url redirects to the new one automatically.

I need to do this in bulk.

There is a text that appears on thousands of permalinks and i want to remove it from them all and keep wp native redirect, because this text appears in random places i cannot make an htaccess rule for all posts.

So for example:

```
http://example.com/cpt1/hello-world-unwanted-word/
http://example.com/cpt2/unwanted-word-hello-world/
http://example.com/cpt3/hello-unwanted-word-world/
```

Should become:

```
http://example.com/cpt1/hello-world/
http://example.com/cpt2/hello-world/
http://example.com/cpt3/hello-world/
```

If someone access the old url redirect to the new one.

Comment: You should check first to make sure the new URLs will not create any duplicate slugs. Having `/cpt1/hello-world/` and `/cpt2/hello-world/` should work because they are different post types and so they have different overall URLs, but if you wind up with two `/cpt1/hello-world/` posts then only one will be accessible.

Comment: I see. They are very different except for these unwanted words. I found a workaround i will post later on!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

```
 function remove_false_words($slug) {
     if(!is_page())
  if (!is_admin()) return $slug;
  $keys_false = array('unwanted','word');
  $slug = explode ('-', $slug);
  $slug = array_diff($slug,$keys_false);
  return implode ('-', $slug);
}
add_filter ('sanitize_title', 'remove_false_words');
```

Then you can use wordpress dashboard to select all posts, bulk edit, Update. And the words will be removed from slugs with native redirect.